# CSS - Como criar um botão ou design como este invertido assim

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como criar uma box assim igual ao botão amarelo da imagem abaixo.

Gostaria de saber simplesmente, como inverter os lados usando CSS e HTML.

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Poste o código já feito para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Esse é o problema nao tenho feito, porque nao sei fazer. nem como... por de lado assim

Comment: E proque raio estão sempre a dar negativos? isto é para ajudar ou para expulsar 99% dos utilizadores????

Comment: Está com +2/-4 no momento. Acho que o problema é que na primeira versão da pergunta, antes das edições, a imagem estava com um formato de link ao invés de estar na pergunta. Desta forma, algumas pessoas não devem ter entendido a sua pergunta e pensado que era uma pergunta mal-formada. O texto da pergunta também teve que passar por uma revisão para ficar legal e algumas pessoas podem não ter entendido ele como estava no começo.

Comment: A comunidade é precisamente para ajudar! Não para fazer o trabalho por ti..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a propriedade CSS `transform` com `perspective` e `rotateY`. Por exemplo:

```css
#botao {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(-1deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="botao">BUY NOW</div>
```

Uma outra forma de fazer isso, sem distorcer o texto (sugestão do colega Bacco), seria assim:

```css
.botao {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.botao:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;  /* compensação da rotação*/
    z-index: -1;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: perspective(10px) rotateY(-1deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="botao">BUY NOW</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Dá pra fazer com CSS2 e bordas, sem distorcer o texto:

```css
.trapezio{
  display:block; position:relative; float:left;
  margin:20px;
  width:200px;                             /* largura da caixa */
  line-height:50px;                        /* altura da caixa  */
  text-align:center;
}

.trapezio:before {
  content:'';
  display:block; position:absolute;
  z-index:-1; width:0; height:100%;
  top:-10px;                               /* = angulo         */ 
  border-right: 200px solid #ccc;          /* largura da caixa */
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;      /* angulo da caixa  */
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;   /* angulo da caixa  */
}

.amarelo:before  {border-right-color:#fe0;}
.azul:before     {border-right-color:#36f;}
.vermelho:before {border-right-color:#f31;}
```

```html
<a class="trapezio"          href="#">BUY NOW</div>
<a class="trapezio amarelo"  href="#">BUY NOW</div>
<a class="trapezio azul"     href="#">BUY NOW</div>
<a class="trapezio vermelho" href="#">BUY NOW</div>
```

Comment: Esse é o mesmo conceito para criar distorção de seta com pseudo-elemento, muito bom.

Comment: Tem um post legal no site já falando de div trapezoidal ou ao menos inclinada, vou ver se acho depois.

Comment: mas eu quero fazer usando o "a" de LINK... e poder também usar varias cores, SUCCESS, DEFAULT... ERROR em link a ?

Comment: @Snoopy12 e qual o problema? Isso não tem nada a ver com o que está na pergunta (e também não muda nada na solução, usei amarelo pq foi o que vc pos na pergunta, se trocar a cor do border, fica como vc quiser).

Comment: Claro mas eu pedi Butao, nao div.

Comment: Mas anyway, pode-me dizer como faço em <aaa> de Links?

Comment: tanto faz o elemento, dá na mesma. Sò por um `<a href="caminho">` em volta

Comment: Eu puns ele nao ficou direito

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/81oregbj/19/ tentei afzer aqui de uma maneira boa e como quero veja  http://jsfiddle.net/81oregbj/19/

Comment: lembre de por um display:block no .trapezioamarelo

Comment: Pode editar esse link ate se tornar direito sff

Comment: Pronto, troquei por A direto na resposta. Outros ajustes você pode fazer usando CSS normalmente, ou consultando postagens mais especificas aqui no próprio site mesmo.

Comment: Ok ja vi, esta bom, mas a ideia era que fosse um butao universal, em baixo poderia criar mais um ".buttao2" com background diferente...e sempre assim.. é piossivel fazer ai, pois isso e com borders... e eu testei e nao da

Comment: Caro @Snoopy12 se quer cores para SUCCESS, DEFAULT... ERROR basta criar uma classe para cada um, como `.btnsuccess { border-right: 200px solid #<cor success>; } .btnerror { border-right: 200px solid #<cor error>; }`, etc. Basta estudar o básico do CSS e aprender como funciona os seletores, o resto é adaptar.

Comment: Posso pedir um fino também?